# Concrete5 package helper - How to fix Fatal error: Call to undefined method NavigationHelper::getURLSegment() error?

Tags: php, helper, concrete5

Sorry, we've looked at a million answers but we either don't understand them or they don't apply.

---

#### Navigation helper:

We have a concrete5 package and have created a helper file at:
/packages/package-name/helpers/navigation.php

It contains the following:

```
<?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die('ACCESS DENIED') ?>

<?php

class NavigationHelper {

    // Get URL segments
    public function getURLSegments() {
        return explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    }

    // Get a specific URL segment
    public function getURLSegment($n) {
        $segs = $this->getURLSegments();
        return count($segs) > 0 && count($segs) >= ($n-1)?$segs[$n]:'';
    }
}
```

---

#### Loading the helper

Then we have an element file where we load the package helper like this:

```
$navHelper = Loader::helper('navigation','package-name');
```

---

#### Calling a method

But when we try to call a method like this:

```
if ($navHelper->getURLSegment(1) == 'whats-on') {
    echo "What's on";
}
```

We see:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method NavigationHelper::getURLSegment()
```

---

We've been starring at the method and package names for an hour so are obviously missing something basic - what are we missing?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($navHelper);`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that's the annoying thing, it's: `object(NavigationHelper)#863 (0) { }` So the helper isn't loading right?

Comment: can you rename `/packages/package-name/helpers/navigation.php` to `/packages/package-name/helper/navigation.php`?

Comment: Yes, but when I do that, none of the other package helpers load so nothing works.

Comment: Got it working by changing the tool file name from `navigation.php` to `package-name_nav.php` and changing the class to include the package name as well. Concrete5 must reserver navigation.php maybe?

Comment: found [this](http://legacy-documentation.concrete5.org/api/class-NavigationHelper.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this problem, custom tool files can't have the same file name as C5 tools.

`navigation.php` was already being used by C5 so changing the file name of my custom file made this all work.